# Android Get Local File Bytes

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to get a byte array of an image saved locally on the phone. I'm using the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload);

    // Look in the Device
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
    // Look in the SD Card
    // startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == 1)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
      Cursor Cur = Upload.this.managedQuery(selectedImage, null, null, null,null);
      if (Cur.moveToFirst()) {
          File Img = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
          long Length = Cur.getLong(Cur.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.SIZE));
          byte[] B = new byte[(int)Length-1];
          FileInputStream ImgIs;
          try {
            ImgIs = new FileInputStream(Img);
            ImgIs.read(B);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i = B.length;
      }
    } 
}
```

But it throws a `FileNotFound exception` on

```
ImgIs = new FileInputStream(Img)
```

How can I get the Bytes?

Comment: Since I answered my own question, should I leave the question here or delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer, see http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg66448.html

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
String absoluteFilePath = cursor.getString(idx);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absoluteFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way I used in my last project:

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
```

In above code, I write the content of bitmap to outputStream  with 100% quality. 
Hope this helps